# material design stretching image to take full browser width with auto height

Tags: css, material-design, angular-material2

the header image i have obviously wont fit to all browser width so i used following css to take auto adjust it to the browser width. however, if i dont specify the height attribute the div does not appear. specifying height as auto or % does not work either. only way it works is giving a fix px. but then that will make the whole design non responsive on small devices as the height will stay constant. please advise

```
<div fxLayout="column">
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch" style="background: url('../../assets/images/header1.png') no-repeat;background-size: 100%;height:300px">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "background-size:cover" instead of 100%.

Comment: image goes away doing that

Comment: Is the div going to be empty except for the background image? If so, just put the image there and give it 100% width and height auto.                                  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Comment: no i am planning to put another div in it with some text and a button

Answer (score 0):

For those using React: the [material-ui-image](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-image) will automatically make the image full screen like so:

```
  <Image style={{marginLeft: '-24px', marginRight: '-24px', marginBottom: '24px', marginTop: '-24px'}}
  src={'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579037611768-298fcaad76e2?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&h=625&q=60'}
  onClick={() => console.log('onClick')}
  aspectRatio={(16 / 9)}
  disableSpinner
  />
```